# ItemsControl: How To Use FindName within ItemsPanelTemplate to access Panel

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomItemsControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <ScrollViewer>
                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="PART_Presenter"/>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel x:Name="PART_StackPanel" IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Trying to access the StackPanel to set Events when children are changed.

```
[TemplatePartAttribute(Name = "PART_StackPanel", Type = typeof(StackPanel))]
[TemplatePartAttribute(Name = "PART_Presenter", Type = typeof(ItemsPresenter))]
public class CustomItemsControl: ItemsControl
{
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        var presenter = (ItemsPresenter)this.Template.FindName("PART_Presenter", this);
        var stackPanel = (StackPanel)this.ItemsPanel.FindName("PART_StackPanel",this);
    }
}
```

Get Exception when I try to locate the StackPanel.

InvalidOperationException:

> This operation is valid only on elements that have this template applied.

Please advise if there is a way to find a TemplatePart within an ItemsPanelTemplate. And when should I expect to know when the ItemsPanelTemplate is applied?

Comment: What events do you need to subscribe to?

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to call `.ApplyTemplate()` on the ItemsPresenter while still in the ItemControl's `OnApplyTemplate` method. Then the call to `.FindName` will succeed.

```
    [TemplatePartAttribute(Name = "PART_StackPanel", Type = typeof(StackPanel))]
    [TemplatePartAttribute(Name = "PART_Presenter", Type = typeof(ItemsPresenter))]
    public class CustomItemsControl : ItemsControl
    {
        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();
            var presenter = (ItemsPresenter)this.Template.FindName("PART_Presenter", this);
            presenter.ApplyTemplate();
            var stackPanel = (StackPanel)this.ItemsPanel.FindName("PART_StackPanel", presenter);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured out that the Loaded event was the one to wait for on an ItemsPanelTemplate. I am able to find the StackPanel using the TemplatePart Name. Thanks to Rick for suggesting the StackPanel should be found within the Presenter.

```
    protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInitialized(e);
        this.Loaded += new Accordion_Loaded;
    }

    void Accordion_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var presenter = (ItemsPresenter)this.Template.FindName("PART_Presenter", this);
        var stackPanel = (StackPanel)this.ItemsPanel.FindName("PART_StackPanel", presenter);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `FindName` method only finds names in a template that has been expanded and the `ItemsPanel` is expanded by the `ItemsPresenter`, not the `ItemsControl`.  In your situation the `"PART_StackPanel"` will always be the child of the `"PART_Presenter"` so you can get a reference to it like this:

```
    var stackPanel = (StackPanel)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(presenter, 0);
```

Comment: Still getting an ArgumentOutOfRangeException on that line. Specified index is out of range or child at index is null. 
Do not call this method if VisualChildrenCount returns zero, indicating that the Visual has no children. 
Parameter name: index
Actual value was 0.  

Also unsure exactly what expanded means when referring to a template. Thanks for the help. Is there another point at which I can expect to find the PART_StackPanel to be added to the presenter?

Comment: You could move your `StackPanel` into the `ControlTemplate` and not use the `ItemsPresenter`.  Or you could look for the `StackPanel` in the `Loaded` event of the `ItemsPresenter`.  Expanded means who is doing the applying of the template.  The `ItemsControl` does not apply the `ItemsPanel` template.